# How to create a list/tibble with different elements even if sometimes they do not exist?

Tags: r

Imagine I have this that needs to be always kept like this because the user doesnt know if all elements exists (depends on prior filtering), but this is the most completed list of elements if they all exist.

```
dataframe1 <- data.frame(x = c(1,2,3),
                           y = c(4,5,6))
dataframe2 <- data.frame(x = c(1,2,3),
                        y = c(4,5,6))
vector1 <- as.numeric(c(1,2,3))
list1 <- as.list(dataframe1, dataframe2)

x <- list(
 "d1" = dataframe1,
 "d2" = dataframe2,
 "vector1" = vector1,
 "list1" = list1
)
```

Having the fact that there are different elements (dataframes, lists, numeric, doubles,...) how is it possible to have a list output of all elements even if some are NULL?

For example, if dataframe1 does not exist, it returns

```
> x <- list(
+   "d1" = dataframe1,
+   "d2" = dataframe2,
+   "vector1" = vector1,
+   "list1" = list1
+ )
Error: object 'dataframe1' not found
```

Comment: I don't understand. Why would you have code that uses the variable if the variable doesn't exist. What exactly is the use case here? Maybe things would be easier if you define a function to build your list. Functions can have optional parameters with default values.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an option:

The function `add_if_valid` checks if the object you are attempting to add to your list exists within the global environment.

- If it does exist, it adds it to the list.
- If it does not exist, it returns `NULL`.

```r
add_if_valid <- function(object) {
   if (exists(deparse(substitute(object)))) {
      return(object)
   } else {
      return(NULL)
   }
}


dataframe1 <- data.frame(x = c(1,2,3),
                         y = c(4,5,6))
dataframe2 <- data.frame(x = c(1,2,3),
                         y = c(4,5,6))
vector1 <- as.numeric(c(1,2,3))
list1 <- as.list(dataframe1, dataframe2)



x <- list(
   "d1" = add_if_valid(dataframe1),
   "d2" = add_if_valid(dataframe2),
   "vector1" = add_if_valid(vector1),
   "list1" = add_if_valid(list1)
)
```

Comment: I am trying to apply add_if_valid function to a element dataframe in position 2 inside a list that I know for sure that exists "list[[2]]" and the function returns NULL... do you know why?

Comment: I have seen that exists() function works with character string that matches with the elements in the environment... the list[[2]] does not exist since in the environment is just list.